# drawRect scaling by 2.3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm subclassing a Sprite, in a drawRectangle method am calling

```
graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100)

graphics.beginFill(0x333333, 1);
graphics.drawRect(10,10,80,80);

graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
graphics.drawRect(20,20,60,60);
```

then in a client extending Sprite calling
    addChild(myRect);
    myRect.height = 100;
    myRect.width = 100;

But the resulting outer rectangle is 233 pixels high and wide???

Any ideas,

Am a noob.

Regards,
shwell.

Comment: Have you add any child to myRect?

Answer (score 1):

No, have since found the solution, a call to stage.setScaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE is required. Thanks for the reply.